# issue with my first ant script

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I have a build.xml files as follows:

```
<project name="My Project" default="jar" basedir=".">

    <property name="dir.src" value="src"/>
    <property name="dir.build" value="build"/>
    <property name="dir.dest" value="dest"/>

    <target name="clean" description="Removing the all generated files.">
        <echo message=" clean starts" />
        <delete dir="${dir.build}"/>
        <delete dir="${dir.dest}"/>
        <echo message=" clean ends" />
    </target>

    <target name="prepare" depends="clean">
        <echo message=" prepare starts" />
        <mkdir dir="${dir.build}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dir.dest}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${dir.src}"/>
        <echo message=" prepare ends" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compilation of all source code.">
        <echo message=" complile starts" />
        <javac srcdir="${dir.src}" destdir="${dir.build}"/>
        <echo message=" complile ends" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="Generates Roseindia.jar file in to the 'dest' directory.">
        <echo message=" jar starts" />
        <jar jarfile="${dir.dest}/roseindia.jar" basedir="${dir.build}"/>
        <echo message=" jar ends" />
    </target>

</project>
```

When i run it i get following op.I think its wrong.I want to do clean,prepare,compile and buld jar .

```
Buildfile: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build.xml
clean:
     [echo]  clean starts
     [echo]  clean ends
prepare:
     [echo]  prepare starts
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest
     [echo]  prepare ends
compile:
     [echo]  complile starts
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
     [echo]  complile ends
jar:
     [echo]  jar starts
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest\roseindia.jar
     [echo]  jar ends
clean:
     [echo]  clean starts
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest
     [echo]  clean ends
prepare:
     [echo]  prepare starts
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest
     [echo]  prepare ends
compile:
     [echo]  complile starts
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
     [echo]  complile ends
clean:
     [echo]  clean starts
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest
     [echo]  clean ends
prepare:
     [echo]  prepare starts
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest
     [echo]  prepare ends
clean:
     [echo]  clean starts
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\build
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Project\Workspaces\Wrk_tst\TestPrj\dest
     [echo]  clean ends
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 669 milliseconds
```

Comment: 51 questions, no accepted answers...

Comment: If you are running `jar` task - everything is ok. `jar` is calling `complile`, `compile` is calling `prepare` and so on

Comment: @LukasKnuth And 512 views of user profile )))

Comment: What command are you using to launch the build? You should just need to use `ant` or `ant jar`. The output looks like what you'd get if you typed `ant jar compile prepare clean`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output it seems like the dependencies are just fine.
When you start the build, since the jar target has dependency the targets are executed just fine.

What is the problem that you are getting? You ant output does not seem to have any errors at all.

Comment: I think that the expected op should be clean,prepare,compile and buld jar .But its again executing them in some arbitary order.Why?

Comment: the sequence is jar, compile, prepare and clean. How are you invoking the ant command? I am surprised why the same target are getting invoked twice.